# File.Create(path) error VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application

Hi i've used the code bellow successfully at the beginning but i don't know what i did so it stopped creating the file `MessageIO.dat` under the folder `(ProgramFiles)\UniWin Activator Data`

i used this code: (result: created only folder `UniWin Activator Data`)

```
Dim UniWinPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "UniWin Activator Data")
Directory.CreateDirectory(UniWinPath)

Dim MsgIO = Path.Combine(UniWinPath, "\MessageIO.dat")
File.Create(MsgIO)
```

and used this: (result: error at the command `File.Create`)

```
Dim UniWinPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "UniWin Activator Data\MessageIO.dat")
File.Create(UniWinPath)
```

and used this: (result: nothing happened)

```
Dim UniWinPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "UniWin Activator Data")
Dim MsgIO = Path.Combine(UniWinPath, "\MessageIO.dat")
File.Create(MsgIO)
```

what's the way to create that file? (I have admin rights already)

Comment: what is the error in the second code?

Comment: Check that the string UniWinPath doesn't contain a backslash at the end. The two strings merged might end up with a double blackslash - I don't know if it makes a difference, but it's worth a go

Comment: problem solved, in the second case: error was `couldn't find a part of the path `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first of your code is perfectly fine. Just change `Dim MsgIO = Path.Combine(UniWinPath, "\MessageIO.dat")` to `Dim MsgIO = Path.Combine(UniWinPath, "MessageIO.dat")`. (Remove the backslash). `Path.Combine` automatically adds one. And as always, to access special directories, make sure you have Administrator Privilleges. The reason the last two codes aren't working is that `File.Create` creates a file in an existing directory. It can't create the directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

When combining paths, you should not specify the "\" char at begining of the second path item as this will mean the root path!
for example, Path.Combine("D:\Folder1", "\MessageIO.dat") will result "\MessageIO.dat". but you have to write Path.Combine("D:\Folder1", "MessageIO.dat") which will return "D:\Folder1\MessageIO.dat"

Note: in windows 7 or above, access to special folders like as Program Files require special permissions! check that your app has such permission. (you can test for other norman folder first to ensure other parts of your code is ok)

Comment: i'll try this currently, btw i already have admin rights by app.manifest file

Comment: this worked but by adding 1 more thing: create directory then create the file messageio.dat

Comment: i said that you have to remove the first backslash from begining of second param in path.combine. the accepted answer is the same, why you didn't accept mine?

Comment: i accept both but his answer has more info (file.create doesn't make a directory automatically if it's not created)

Comment: @saeedserpooshan this answer deserves an upvote then.